# Get information about trading commissions in Binance API

Tags: rest, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I want to get info about commissions on Binance. Especially about trading commissions (exchange operations, for example I want to buy ETH and pay by BTC). I've looked over all binance git: https://github.com/binance-exchange and found nothing about that. 
The closest what I found is account information. Using curl GET /api/v3/account we can get response that has (full example is [here](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md)):

```
{
  "makerCommission": 15,
  "takerCommission": 15,
  "buyerCommission": 0,
  "sellerCommission": 0
}
```

But I don't really get what maker and taker commissions mean, 15 is very strange number. And buyer and seller too because it is very suspicious that they are 0.

I'm pretty sure that it should be a way to get this info, because, for example, HitBTC has such info: https://api.hitbtc.com/#get-trading-commission

I will be very grateful for any help and information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: These are maker-taker commisions, not trading fees. People who provide liquidity are charged different fees from people taking liquidity. See [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/55152/what-is-taker-and-maker-fee) from the bitcoin stack exhange for more information. So the `15` is a percentage, you start with a 0.15% commision and depending on your last 30 days volume it may be lower. If you want to get trading fees you will get them when retreiving orders (0.1% according to [this page](https://www.binance.com/fees.html)).

Answer (score 1):

As @Yann39 said, just divide the value by `10000`, to get the fee as percent

e.g: `makerCommission : 15` <=> `15/10000` = `0.0015` = `0.15%`

Comment: Thanks, where did you read this?

Comment: Nowhere, I found this by deducing .

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't really get what maker and taker commissions mean, 15 is very strange number.

In trading, fees/commission are assumed to be in [*basis points*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_point) units, aka *bps* (pronounced as *bips*), ‰ (per mille) symbol.

Normally, trading fees are a fraction of a percent, so that expressing them in percentage units would always require `0.` prefix which is a nuisance to pronounce, e.g. "fee is 15 hundredths of a percent" vs "fee is 15 bps".